# Generate dynamic control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to create a dynamic control in my ASPX page. The control is like textbox, button, label, audio, video etc. And also generate the HTML page so i can drag and drop or bind this control.

So how can it be done? Please give me some advice or code project so i can understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Mansinh i'added sample of place holder

Comment: @Candie:Thanks But i dont want to that type of custom controll but i need generate one html page on button click.I wants to give facality to user they drag and drop lable,textbox,video or button controll and also i wants to give facality to bind this controll like user darg and drop lable and than bind with another controll this contain some data so it will done.so give me anser how it can be done. I mean how i generate html page and how generate controll

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on CodeProject that details how to create dynamic controls in ASP.NET and add them to the page using a PlaceHolder.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8114/Dynamically-Created-Controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: :thnaks but i wants to some diffrent think like visual studio controll tool box.So i can drag and drop my lable or textbox and also bind this controll.Please give me some instruction or code project.

Comment: @Mansinh Well something like this perhaps? Do you want to make your own custom controls in ASP.NET? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-ajax-server-controls-with-client-side-functionality/

Comment: :Yes i want to make my custome controll but not google map.I just create lable,button,textbox,audio and video controll.If you have any idea than help me i it can be done.\

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific @Mansinh. Why would you need to make custom label, button and textbox controls when ASP.NET already has them built in? And I realize that you may not want a Google Maps control but that tutorial covers other fundamentals in making other custom ASP.NET controls.

Comment: :I have one project.In this project i want generate html page like click on button and html page is generated.Than user directly drag and drop button, textbox,audio, vodio controll on html page .And i also give facality to bind ths controll.Suppose usert drop video controll and bind than video is autometically palyed.